# Triggering an Interface in Kotlin for Android

Tags: android, interface, kotlin

There is a specific implementation of interface when it comes to using Kotlin for Android: triggering an interface from a fragment. Consider the common scenario where a Fragment must communicate a UI action to the parent Activity. In Java, we would define the interface, create a "listener" instance of it, and implement/override actions in interface parents. It is the creating a listener instance that is not so straightforward to me. After some googling, I found an implementation example but I do not understand why it works. Is there a better way to do this? Why must it be implemented the way it is below?

```
    class ImplementingFragment : Fragment(){

  private lateinit var listener: FragmentEvent
  private lateinit var vFab: FloatingActionButton

  //Here is the key piece of code which triggers the interface which is befuddling to me
  override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
          super.onAttach(context)
          if(context is FragmentEvent) {
              listener = context
          }
      }

    //Notice the onClickListener using our interface listener member variable
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v: View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
            vFab = v?.findViewById(R.id.fh_fab)
            vFab.setOnClickListener{listener.SomethingHappened()}
        return v
    }  


}



interface FragmentEvent{
    fun SomethingHappened()
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how `context is FragmentEvent` would ever be true. In addition, that if could be simplified to `listener = context as? FragmentEvent`.

Comment: Neither do I, yet it works. I'm wondering if there is a more standard way? The example was found here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/169885/android-fragments-tutorial-introduction-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code `lateinit var listener: FragmentEvent` should be initialized and can't be `null`. So `onAttach` should looks like

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is FragmentEvent) {
        listener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context!!.toString() + " must implement FragmentEvent")
    }
}
```

In this case if you forget to implement `FragmentEvent` in `Activity` you'll got an exception, otherwise callback is ready to use.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. What I was looking for is an explanation as to why context would be an Interface. Doesn't context normally have to do with an activity or a fragment, not such a primitive class? And is this normal implementation? I am not seeing where the interface variable is instantiated.

Comment: @JoshRibeiro `context` in this case is parent activity context with all relations, so `FragmentEvent` object can be initialized if it is present in there. This style is recommended by google. If you are create new `Fragment` from dropdown menu (New -> Fragment -> Fragment(blank)) you'll see the same implementation

Comment: Thank you Stanislav. I wasn't aware that it included items such as Interfaces, but your explanation about context being tied to a parent activity makes sense if that is given. I will mark this answered. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: @StanislavBondar won't this leak listener when the Fragment is detached? Is it not necessary to set the listener to null in `onDetach()` when using lateinit var?

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a try catch block and get the classic Java pattern

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        listener = context as YourInterface
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        Log.d("TAG", "MainActivity must implement YourInterface")
    }
}
```

the 'as' keyword can be used in to replicate java explicit typecasting in kotlin

```
val customItem = arguments?.getSerializable("KEY") as ArrayList<Custom>
```