# Why l can`t set listener in Kotlin?

Tags: android, callback, kotlin

I have OnClickInterface (with method fun onClickShape()) Main.class, and FlipFragment.class and ImageView (which called image in my code). My goal is make listener for image.

```
interface OnClickInterface {
  fun onClickShape()
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initTabs()
    var flip = FlipFragment()
    flip.listener = object : OnClickInterface {
      override fun onClickShape() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Shape Pressed")
        ToastUtils.showSuccessMessage(baseContext, "sometext")
      }

    } 
  }

  fun initTabs() {
    var adapter = TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    mViewPager.adapter = adapter
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
  }
}
```

onCreate in FlipFragment

```
var image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fShapeView)
    image.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
      Log.d("FlipFragment", "PRESSED")
      if (listener != null)
        listener!!.onClickShape()
    })
```

App was loading well, without errors. But when I pressed in the image I show in my log FlipFragment: PRESSED that's mean that my application call method from FragmentFlip, not override method from MainActivity. Why?

I searched error . My app show NPE here.

```
 flip.listener = object : OnClickInterface {
              override fun onClickShape() {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Shape Pressed")
                ToastUtils.showSuccessMessage(baseContext, "someText")
              }}
```

Why listener = null . I defined it with anonymous class.

All code in FlipFragment

```
class FlipFragment : Fragment() {
  private var layout = R.layout.view_flip
  var listener: OnClickInterface? = null

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view: View
    view = inflater!!.inflate(layout, container, false)
    var image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fShapeView)
    image.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
      Log.d("FlipFragment", "PRESSED")
        if (listener != null){
         listener!!.onClickShape()}
    })
    return view
  }

  companion object {
    fun getInstanse(): FlipFragment {
      var args = Bundle()
      var flipFragment = FlipFragment()
      flipFragment.arguments = args
      return flipFragment
    }

  }


}
```

If you need all code it is FragmentPagerAdapter.class

```
class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
  var tabs: Array<String> = arrayOf("Flip", "Multi")

  override fun getItem(position: Int) = when(position){
      0 -> FlipFragment.getInstanse()
      1 -> Mulit.getInstanse() //it is empty now
    else -> FlipFragment.getInstanse()
    }


  override fun getPageTitle(position: Int) = tabs[position]


  override fun getCount() = tabs.size
}
```

Comment: Not enough info. Provide us with `FlipFragment` code

Comment: @DimaRostopira added all code of this class

Comment: `getInstance()` looks strange... Show code, where you add fragment

Comment: @DimaRostopira I have changed MainActivity description and add FragmentPagerAdapter.class

Comment: I was asking for code, where you attach fragment to activity. Do you use `fragmentManager` or this fragment is included in `R.layout.activity_main`?

Comment: @DimaRostopira i attach fragmentManager     var adapter = TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    mViewPager.adapter = adapter

Comment: I see you only create instance of fragment, but don't see where you use it

Comment: Why are you not using onAttach to get the listener instance from context? i think this is the right form to get the listener.

Comment: I attach it in tabInit and try to add listener in OnCreate method to the image which situated at the FlipFragment

Comment: In `onCreate` you are creating **local** variable `var flip = FlipFragment()`, attaching listener to it, and then it disappears (if you attached whole `onCreate`)

Comment: What is the point of the "OnClickInterface"? You already have an OnClickListener attached to your image and it works, why make things more complicated?

Comment: @victorldavila It is good idea, but I don`t know how to do it. I'll try search about it.

Comment: maybe this link can help you @VadimMarchenko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513664/triggering-an-interface-in-kotlin-for-android